# Need a reg expression to get numbers from url using preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex

```
function strip_cdata($string)
{
    preg_match_all('/<!\[cdata\[(.*?)\]\]>/is', $string, $matches);
    return str_replace($matches[0], $matches[1], $string);
}
```

I use the above function to extract text from cdata, but I don't know how to modify the reg expression to get a number from the url below.

```
http://blah.somesite.com/anytextcouldbehere/2828842087.html
```

Specifically, I need to get "2828842087" from the above url.  It will always be numbers and be between the last "/" and ".html".

Thanks

Comment: How do *cdata* and URLs relate?

Comment: try preg_match_all('/\d+/is', $string, $matches);

Comment: I was just using that function as an example.  They don't relate.  I will create a new function that will get those numbers from a url.  I just need the reg expression.

Comment: You must not use regex on XML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to use regexp here:

```
$url = 'http://blah.somesite.com/anytextcouldbehere/2828842087.html';

$data = parse_url($url);
$number = basename($data['path'], '.html');
```

Comment: I'd probably use this if matching non-numeric file names is not an issue.

Comment: Thanks @dfsq!   Worked great.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the regular expression:

```
$url = 'http://blah.somesite.com/anytextcouldbehere/2828842087.html';
if( preg_match('@/(\d+)\.html$@', $url, $matches) ){
    $number = $matches[1];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also try this one instead of regex:

```
$url = 'http://blah.somesite.com/anytextcouldbehere/2828842087.html';
$info = pathinfo($url);
$num = $info['filename'];
echo $num;
```

Comment: Is that quicker than using preg_replace_all?

Comment: this cannot be compared to regex, pathinfo works even on non numbers if your aim is to get the filename only, pathinfo is more appropriate as regex expression will be modified if the corresponding url contains other numbers

Answer (score 0):

use this regex

```
/\d*/

preg_match_all('/\d*/is', $string, $matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
preg_match_all('/^http\:\/\/([\w\/\.]+)\/(<?P<num>[\d]+)\.html$/',$url,$matches);
```

now the number is in $matches['num']. that is an array like this:

```
Array(0=>2828842087)
```

good luck